# Cannot move Planar Track bounding box points

Tags: tracking

When setting up the Plane Tracker in the Movie Clip Editor to fit the replacement image into the background target, I cannot move the plane geometry vertex points to the location points on the bg image.  I can select the box outline, but I cannot select or move individual vertices.
I tried switching the mouse button select preferences from LMB to RMB but that did not work.  I can select and move 2d trackers or anything else in the interface, but not the plane track box.
I am using v2.79 on an 2006 MacPro running Lion 10.7.5.

Comment: so [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2brgL.gif) is the part that is not working for you?

Comment: Yes,  that is the problem.  I cannot adjust the corners of the plane object.  The vertices simply do not respond to my mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem is.  I am using the MAYA Input User Preferences, and in the Clip preferences there is no input setting for moving the Plane Marker as there is in the Blender input settings. If I switch to the Blender Input Prefs the mouse manipulations work. So I had to create a new input binding under the Maya Input Prefs just like the one in the Blender Prefs.  It works now.

The input binding is under Input->Clip->Clip Editor->Slide Plane Marker.